# How to check if the date belongs to current week or not?

Tags: java, android, date

I have the date and time stored in preferences as `Long`:

```
// put
SharedPreferences settings =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
settings.edit().putLong("pref_datetime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
// get
Date date2 = new Date(settings.getLong("pref_datetime", 0));
```

Once date is extracted, how could I check if it belongs to the current week (starting on Monday) or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Calendar` instance to create this Monday and next Monday `Date` instances based on the current date then check that your date lies between them.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Date monday = c.getTime();

Date nextMonday= new Date(monday.getTime()+7*24*60*60*1000);

boolean isThisWeek = date2.after(monday) && date2.before(nextMonday);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);` instead of `c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);`?

Comment: Thanks Rupesh, yes HOUR_OF_DAY is preferable

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can construct a Calendar, and use `getField(int)` to get both the Calendar.YEAR and the Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR. When those are the same, the two Dates are from the same week.</strike>

When constructing the Calendar, also call `setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)` to make sure the weeks start on Monday (if you don't, it depends on the current locale).

---

After @SiKelly's objection that this won't work reliably in the end of December, beginning of January:

1. Compare WEEK_OF_YEAR.
2. If not equal, it is a different week.
3. If equal, it could be the wrong year, but that is hard to check. So just also check that the difference in getTime() is less than 8 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (eight days to be on the safe side).

(you could do step 3 first. then you avoid having to construct the calendar at all in many cases).

Comment: I have had trouble relying on week of year before as it is a somewhat slippery concept. The weeks at the beginning and end of the year straddle 2 years, and therefore you may get 52 or 1 depending on the implementation.

Comment: @SiKelly: Good catch. That would be a problem.

Comment: @SiKelly: just for gaining knowledge, I would like to know that, will my approach work in all situations?

Comment: @MehulJoisar: I think not. You can have Dec 30th and Jan 1st in the same week (will be 52 or 1), but in different years. So checking for same year won't work.

Comment: @Thilo: but I have added condition for checking year as well weeknumber both.won't it work fine in such situation?

Comment: `if(current_year==year )` that will be false for Dec 30th and Jan 1st.

Comment: @Thilo: I got your point. you're right.it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Calendar` to calculate week number for today and your date also,then simpy try to match it,

```
// put
SharedPreferences settings =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
settings.edit().putLong("pref_datetime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
// get
Date date2 = new Date(settings.getLong("pref_datetime", 0));              

          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
          int current_year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          int current_week_number = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
          calendar.setTime(date2);
          int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          int week_number= calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
          if(current_year==year && current_week_number==week_number)
          {
              //same
          }
          else
          {
              //different
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private boolean  is_ThisWeek(Date date2){

        Date now =new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int diffInDays = (int)( (now.getTime() - date2.getTime()) 
                 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(now);
        int reslut = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int days_before = get_days_before(reslut);

        if (diffInDays<days_before) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "this week", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"not this week", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
     }
    int get_days_before(int reslut){
        int days_before = 0;
        switch (reslut) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            days_before=1;
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            days_before=2;
            break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            days_before=3;
            break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            days_before=4;
            break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            days_before=5;
            break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            days_before=6;
            break;
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            days_before=7;
            break;
        }
        return days_before;
    }
```